# Generic Type for Context when setting optionsbuilder

Tags: c#, generics

I have class where at present I am defining the MigrateDatabase method as abstract which each class that inherits from it needs to implement

So in my base class I have

```
    public MyService()
    {
        public abstract void MigrateDatabase(string connectionString);
        public void SetupDatabase()
        { 
            MigrateDatbase(connection string here);
        }
    }
    
    protected override void MigrateDatabase(string connectionString)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TransactionMonitoringDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
        sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
        {
            sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name);
                    sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 10,
                        maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                        errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                    sqlOptions.CommandTimeout(240);
         });
         using var db = new TransactionMonitoringDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
         //Only do this when the overall function starts up
         db.Database.Migrate();
    }
```

This is not really a good way to do this because I have to duplicate all the code above for the sake of the fact that each service has a different context type

How can I implement this with inheritance where all I need to do is have a function that returns back the type of the context?

This is more complex because of the DbContextOptionsBuilder having a generic constructor

Paul

Comment: How about `void MigrateDatabase<TContext>(...) where TContext : DbContext` and then use `TContext` instead of `TransactionMonitoringDbContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a factory function for your context:

```
protected override void MigrateDatabase<TContext>(
    Func<DbContextOptions<TContext>, TContext> contextFactory,
    string connectionString)
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>();

    // ...

    using var db = contextFactory(optionsBuilder.Options);

    // ...
}
```

Then call like this:

```
MigrateDatabase(opt => new TransactionMonitoringDbContext(opt), "connection string");
```

Comment: ok but what would go into the factory function?

Comment: @Paul I've given an example: `opt => new TransactionMonitoringDbContext(opt)`